# Need a better solution for the app development issue

Tags: android, performance, android-intent

i'm developing an app to view stored pdf files as below.

admin can save docs as a pdf and stored in the server.in other side mobile users can download pdf to the sd card and can read the file.these parts already developed.

my problems is while mobile users reading the document,admin edited the same pdf and replace it(store in server).but mobile user still reading downloaded old version file.
how can i solve this problem.I need help from the expertise.

Comment: weird idea.. dont store them locally.. use Google docs mobile viewer and pass url to both client and admin http://googlemobile.blogspot.in/2010/06/google-docs-viewer-on-mobile-browsers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only answer for your question is running a [`Android-Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) to continue check for updates on your server if server has newly or edited pdf file available then notify user to download that file.

**EDIT:** As per behalf of **Renard**  there is also other option call [Android-C2DM](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/) as I never used this that's why I didn't suggest you.

Anyway take a look at..

Comment: thanks for your answer.What do you mean service? track using web service or something?

Comment: Here service means [Android-Servie](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) in that you have to call your webservice for check updation on server.

Comment: @Renard Yes i am agree with you, because if i write Service for the continuous checking then it would drain battery and processing power. Instead there is a better solution known as **C2DM** which is used to send notification from server to device. So whenever Admin make any changes at server side, then user will notify that a particular article is modified.

Comment: @Renard - Thanks for it. I edited my answer. Actually I never try for this.